# How to generate hash from subroutine?

Tags: perl, subroutine, hash

I am trying to collect some snapshots of my db and do some math with it , but I'm failing to return my hash from my subroutine ...

As you can see I have 2 hashes %dbmcfg,%bufsnap,%dbsnap I have clubbed these 3 into one hash my %snaps =(%bufsnap,%dbmcfg,%dbsnap); , I am new to Perl, and i came to know there is scope concept of the variables contrast to the shell where i'm successful in writing functions and calling them .

Im getting some goal decleration of variable error ........This returning  hash is important to me as i need to pass it to another functions and do some math in that sub routine

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub snapshots() {
    my @tmpdbmcfg = grep /=/,`db2 "get snapshot for dbm"`;
    my %dbmcfg;
    foreach (@tmpdbmcfg) {
        chomp;
        s/^\s*//;
        s/\s*$//;
        my ($col3,$col4) = split /\s*=\s*/,$_,2;
        $dbmcfg{$col3}=$col4;
    }
    #print Dumper(\%dbmcfg);
    #if ($dbmcfg{'Max agents overflow'} != 0 ) {
    #print "fine\n";
    #} else {print "Not\n"; }

    my @tmpbufarr=grep /=/,`db2 "get snapshot for bufferpools on awdrt"`;
    my %bufsnap;

    foreach (@tmpbufarr) {
        chomp;
        s/^\s*//;
        s/\s*$//;
        my ($bufsnapkey,$bufsnapval) = split /s*=s*/,$_,2;
        $bufsnap{$bufsnapkey} = $bufsnapval;
    }

    my @tmpdbarr =grep /=/,`db2 "get snapshot for db on awdrt"`;
    my %dbsnap;
    foreach (@tmpdbarr) {
        chomp;
        s/^\s*//;
        s/\s*$//;
        my ($dbsnapkey,$dbsnapvalue) = split /s*=s*/,$_,2;
        $dbsnap{$dbsnapkey} = $dbsnapvalue;
    }
    my %snaps = (%bufsnap,%dbmcfg,%dbsnap);
    #print Dumper(\%snaps);
    return (\%snaps);
}

&snaps;
#print Dumper(\%snapis);
```

Help is appreciated ..........

Comment: Add proper indentation. That will make things 10 times easier for you, and for us.

Comment: Your subroutine is snapshots, but you are calling it as snaps? Also, the return value is not being collected..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return simple lists and scalar values, but more complex structures will not work, and hashes when returned will be expanded into their keys and values. You may do something like this:

```
sub foo {
    my (%hash1, %hash2);   # hashes lexically scoped to sub only
    return {               # { .. } creates hash reference
        hash1 => \%hash1,  # these are key/value pairs 
        hash2 => \%hash2,  # hashes now exported outside the sub
    };
}

my $href = foo();          # $href->{hash1} now points to \%hash1
```

You can of course improvise:

```
return (\%hash1, \%hash2);
...
my ($href1, $href2) = foo();  # two hrefs are returned
```

Comment: **thanks man** , you always help me on-time .....I got clarity on this .thanks a lot once again .........

Comment: by the way , any suggestions on IDE for that indentation to be automatic or vi editor still the best

Answer (score 0):

A couple of extra tips.

If you're going to put a prototype on your function (which you probably shouldn't do, because [Perl prototypes don't really do what people think they do](http://web.archive.org/web/20080421062920/http://library.n0i.net/programming/perl/articles/fm_prototypes/)), then you probably shouldn't then call the function using an ampersand - as one of the side-effects of the ampersand is [to turn off prototype checking](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes).

In general:

a/ You don't want to use prototypes
b/ You don't want to use the old-style (using an ampersand) function calls